# Yii framework - Different validation rules depending on selected options

Tags: php, model, validation, yii

Is it possible to create model rules that are dependent from selection?

I have a model "Deposit" which is used to enter the money transfer details..I have drop down list with two possible choices "Cash Transfer","Cheque Transfer", and i have fields cash_deposit_date,bank_name.. which is required only for cash transfer and cheque_date, cheque_no and in_favour_of.. which is required only at the time of cheque transfer.. how can i do that..?

I know i can use scenarios like this,

```
$model=new Deposit("cash_transfer");
```

or

```
$model=new Deposit("cheque_transfer");
```

but how can I change scenario depending on the value selected in dropdown list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just do this:

Generated HTML:

```
<form>
....
<select name="scenario">
    <option value="cash_transfer">Cash Transfer</option>
    <option value="cheque_transfer">Checque Transfer</option>
</select>
....
</form>
```

Code:

```
// allow only lowercase letters and underscore
$scenario = preg_replace('/[^a-z_]/', '', $_POST['scenario']);

if (!empty($scenario)) {
    $model = new Deposit($scenario);
} else {
    die('Missing scenario!');
}
```

Comment: You should check that given scenario is really one of your combo to avoid security problems..

Answer (score 1):

Extending from jupaju answer,

That dropdown list also a model field(transfer_type), so I have done something like this..
After checking POST values are set, I use `$model->scenario = $model->transfer_type==1 ? 'cash_transfer':'cheque_transfer'` to change the scenario.

### My code is

```
$model=new Deposit;
// Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
// $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
if(isset($_POST['Deposit']))
{
    $model->attributes=$_POST['Deposit'];
    $model->scenario = $model->transfer_type==1 ? 'cash_transfer':'cheque_transfer';    
    if($model->save())
        $this->redirect(array('admin'));
}
$this->render('create',array('model'=>$model));
```

Now it is working..

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to use a personalized validation rule in your model and then check if the model's "scenario" property is set to one or other option.

You can read more about custom validation rules in [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model)

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: it is not necessary to use personalized validation rule to achieve this. i am just changing the scenario name dynamically by using the value selected in dropdownlist.. i posted it in comment.. anyway thanx for ur reply..

Answer (score 0):

This is more simple form me

**In your model put:**

```
public $pay_type;
/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        ...
        array('pay_type', 'required'),
        array('cash_deposit_date', 'validationTransfer'),
        ...

    );
}

public function validationTransfer($attribute,$params)
{
     // this a sample, put all your need
     if($this->pay_type=='cash_transfer' and $this->cash_deposit_date==='')
          $this->addError('cash_deposit_date','If you will pay to Cash Transfer, enter your cahs deposit date');

     // this a sample, put all your need
     if($this->pay_type=='cheque_transfer' and $this->cheque_date==='')
          $this->addError('cheque_date','If you will pay to Cheque Transfer, enter your cheque date');

     // this a sample, put all your need
     if($this->pay_type=='cheque_transfer' and $this->cheque_no==='')
          $this->addError('cheque_no','If you will pay to Cheque Transfer, enter your Cheque No');

}
```

**In the view into your widget form**

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'pay_type',array('class'=>'control-label')); ?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'pay_type',array("cash_transfer"=>"Cash Transfer","cheque_transfer"=>"Cheque Transfer"),array('class'=>'form-control','empty'=>'Pay Type...')); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'pay_type',array('class'=>'help-block')); ?>
```

Note: css class like "help-block", "control-label", "form-control"  on witget form are optionals, maybe you use Bootstrap 3 and it will looks good